# Primary and Secondary DNS on two internet connections, one server

Tags: dns

Currently my network setup is as follows:

1 server, 3 ethernet cards.

eth0 - ISP1
eth1 - ISP2
eth2 - local network.

What would be the proper way of configuring primary and secondary DNS?
Using tinydns.

Current configuration:
2 tinydns services running on the same machine, each configured on a different ip (NS1 = eth0, NS2 = eth1)

each dns configuration contains both records:
NS1:

```
.domain.lv:10.10.10.10:ns.domain.lv
.domain.lv:20.20.20.20:ns2.domain.lv
@domain.lv:10.10.10.10:mail.didzis.lv:10:256::
@domain.lv:20.20.20.20:mail.domain.lv:20:256::
+www.domain.lv:10.10.10.10
```

NS2:

```
.domain.lv:20.20.20.20:ns.domain.lv
.domain.lv:10.10.10.10:ns2.domain.lv
@domain.lv:10.10.10.10:mail.didzis.lv:10:256::
@domain.lv:20.20.20.20:mail.domain.lv:20:256::
+www.domain.lv:20.20.20.20
```

The second link is more like a backup in case the first one fails and vice versa. Wont this configuration fail if eth1 is down and the www resolves to 20.20.20.20

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of configuration can work but there will be issues. What you want to do is make the TTL of the "www.domain.lv." record really low. The TTL tells other DNS servers how long they are allowed to cache the response. The lower you make it, the quicker clients will notice when one of your ISPs is down, but making it lower will also make it so they have to recheck the IP address more often, which will cost time. 300 seconds (5 minutes) might be a reasonable compromise but I would suggest making it longer (like 900 seconds) if you can afford for a failover to take 15 minutes.

By the way, I don't know how you set the TTL for a record in tinydns. I've never used it (and frankly I find its syntax quite cryptic and scary if your transcripts of the zonefiles are anything to go by).

This will all work fine when both ISPs are up.

The major drawback of this solution is that, when one of the ISPs is down, there will be DNS resolution delays no matter what. Lucky clients will try to query the nameserver that's still responding and get back the IP address that works for an answer. Unlucky clients will try to query the nameserver that's down first. This won't work. They will eventually fail over to the one that's still up and get a working IP address, but you must be prepared for a delay of (maybe) several seconds before this happens.